# Why doesn't JobScheduler work in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

At present, I test JobScheduler , I invoke startServer() from a activity, I think that the system can invoke `Log.e("cw","OK")` every 5s, but I failed, what wrong with my code ?

1: The following code are converted from Java automatically in Android Studio 3.0, I think it's not good Kotlin code, could you fix it?

2: Do I need to start service before invoking  `mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)` ?

```
val startServiceIntent = Intent(this, ScheduledJobService::class.java)
startService(startServiceIntent)
```

3: Will the system keep to invoke `Log.e("cw","OK")` every 5s even if I finish the APP?

**Code**

```
 private fun startServer(){
        Log.e("cw","Start Server")

        val mJobScheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

        val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(123, ComponentName(packageName, ScheduledJobService::class.java!!.getName()))
                .setPeriodic(5000)
                .build()

        mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)

}

private fun CancelServer(){

        Log.e("cw","Stop Server")

        val mJobScheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
        mJobScheduler.cancelAll()

}



class ScheduledJobService : JobService() {

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        Log.e("cw","Start")
        Thread(Runnable { completeJob(params) }).start()
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        Log.e("cw","Stop")
        return false
    }

    fun completeJob(parameters: JobParameters) {
       Log.e("cw","OK")
       jobFinished(parameters, false)
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service
  android:name="bll.ScheduledJobService"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
</service>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Javadoc explains,

> Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval, not more than once per period. You have no control over when within this interval this job will be executed, only the guarantee that it will be executed at most once within this interval.

There's no way Android is going to run your job every five seconds; in fact, the Developer Console will accuse your application of "Bad behavior due to excessive wakeups" for anything above 10 wakeups per hour.

Clearly, this behavior has nothing to do with Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks! I set 5s only in order to test, could you tell me if my code is correct?

Comment: I compared it with my production code, looks pretty much the same. I couldn't find anything to point my finger at.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to start service before invoking mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo) ? and more , will the system keep to invoke Log.e("cw","OK") even if I finish the APP?

Comment: I have found some sample code to do `val startServiceIntent = Intent(this, ScheduledJobService::class.java)
startService(startServiceIntent)` before `mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)`

Comment: I never heard of the concept of "starting a system service". Yes, the system will keep invoking your job in the background, it's the main point of the job scheduler service.

Comment: "Starting a background service" is a separate (older) feature from letting the job scheduler run your jobs.

Comment: I hardly to test JobScheduler because the system  run the periodically  task about every15 min even if I  setPeriodic(60*1000) , it's a long time for test.  is there a good way to do it?

Comment: I'm struggling with that, too. In my experience, while the phone is connected to a usb debugging session, you actually get a run each minute. But that was with a Lollipop phone, it may well be different with later versions.

Comment: I test my code in API 23, `Log.e("cw","OK")` can be invoked quickly per 5s;  
But in API 26, `Log.e("cw","OK")` can be invoked about per 15min, why?

Comment: Google keeps tightening the loop of battery usage by apps. In some version they also had a bug of some kind that caused excessive wakeups and battery drain. Newest Androids refuse to wake up your phone when it's sitting idle and not charging, except in quite sparse "maintenance windows".

Comment: I test it on Android Studio Emulator both API 26 and API 23